# Windows Forms chart problem with changing the interval of the axis

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a chart in winForms and I have an area series and point series. When I run the program, both series are at an offset of about 0.3 to the left of where they should have been on the x axis. Can anybody help?

Here is the code:

```
        chart1.DataSource = dt;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "0";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
        chart1.Series["תחום הפתרונות האפשריים"].BorderWidth = 0;
        float[] OptimalPoint = CalculateOptimalPt(convertEq(z), ListArToAr(points));
        chart1.Series["פיתרון אופטימלי"].Points.AddXY(OptimalPoint[0], OptimalPoint[1]);
        chart1.Series["פיתרון אופטימלי"].Points[0].MarkerSize = 10;
        chart1.Series["תחום הפתרונות האפשריים"].XValueMember = "X_Value";
        chart1.Series["תחום הפתרונות האפשריים"].YValueMembers = "Y_Value";
        chart1.Series["תחום הפתרונות האפשריים"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "";
```

Here is the outcome:

[Current Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Ed1.png)

The whole blue area should be 0.3 points to the left, as well as the yellow dot. Can anybody help?

EDIT 1:
progress update:
I have figured what exactly the problem is, I still don't know how to fix it. The problem is in the line

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

because when I change the interval from the automatic the x axis values move 0.3 tiles but the area series and the point series stay where they were. How do I update the graph to make the area series and the point series move along with the new interval of the x axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

all you need to do is set a minimum and maximum for the X and Y as follows:

```
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 10;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
```

Best of luck